# Keras loss went from small value to inf suddenly

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Hi does anyone know what causes training loss suddenly became inf?

I am training a small network with a few conv/batchnorm/relu/maxpool/dense layers with SGD. Ytrain is (?, 1) shape so for a batch size of 1 each time y true is a tensor of (1, 1). I use a custom loss function:

```
def my_loss(y, yhat):
  mse = keras.losses.mean_squared_error(y, yhat)
  return K.sqrt(mse)
```

And the training log shows:

```
52725/2483247 [..............................] - ETA: 5:54:20 - loss: 0.0759
52731/2483247 [..............................] - ETA: 5:54:20 - loss: 0.0759
52737/2483247 [..............................] - ETA: 5:54:20 - loss: inf
52743/2483247 [..............................] - ETA: 5:54:20 - loss: inf
```

Training data are positive numbers contains no zero or nan, for sample 52725 - 52743 the values are a single feature ranging from 0.09 to 72.7. I am not sure where the inf is from. Any idea?

Comment: divide by zero?

Comment: Seems like an exploding gradient problem, general cause is bad initialization or high learning rate.

Comment: That's possible, I just don't immediately know where the divided by zero is from.

Comment: I didn't set the initializer, I'll give it a go. Learning rate was 0.00002 so possibly not it.

Comment: @Ann try to print the predicted labels and, which optimizer are you using?

Comment: @Minato, I was using 'SGD(lr=lr, momentum=0.9, decay=(0.01 / epochs), nesterov=True)`, now just added **clipvalue=0.5** and random initializer, will see how it goes. I am trying to predict some time series so the **label** is the ytrue value. I use custom metrics to show the ytrue and ypred values, they pretty much match up.

Comment: @Ann the 'inf' you see is because the MSE loss explodes, the reason is that one or both of the terms you pass in the MSE functions are going to infinity. The most obvious suspect would be that some/all of the network weights are going towards infinity causing the predicted vector to go to infinity. I'd try vanilla SGD with decently low learning rate to see what is going on

Comment: @Minato, thank you very much. After applying the clipvalue it's been training fine ever since. It should have passed the point it normally went into inf which was quite early in the training. So looks like this has fixed it. You're right, when the loss is inf, the ypred was nan. I am using learning rate 0.00002 with ReduceLROnPlateau.

Comment: @Ann seems like a nice strategy

Comment: @Ann saved my day, but my problem wasn't caused by gradient explosion and clipvalue didn't help, it was caused by ypred of -inf